# Cocoa: Key view loop stopping at custom NSView

Tags: cocoa, nsview

I'm implementing a custom NSView which draws a graph. The tab key loop is stopping on the NSView, and then getting stuck there.  This is one of several views, the other which are system-provided classes.  These are presented at a peer level within a window.  Tabbing between the peer views works fine.

It's set up as follows:

1. I load a window from a XIB.
2. The NSView is programmatically allocated and added to the window.
3. I have confirmed that the window's AutorecalculatesKeyViewLoop is set (Just for fun, I also have tried recalculateKeyViewLoop after adding the view).
4. The view behaves properly in all other respects, including resizing.
5. If I click on a peer object and then tab from it, when tabbing, other peer objects are made key as they should.
6. When the custom NSView is made key, the tab key stops advancing the key view to a different peer view.  Shift-tab will not back up.

Near as I can tell, this should be automatic, but it's not working.

I have acceptFirstResponder, becomeFirstResponder, and resignFirstResponder set to return YES.

I have confirmed resignFirstResponder is never called.

I am probably missing an obvious step when configuring the custom NSView; any suggestions?